# How to get an array from HTML document with duplicated attributes in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML document as follows.

```
<div data-map_id="0"></div>
<div data-map_id="0"></div>
<div data-map_id="1"></div>
<div data-map_id="1"></div>
<div data-map_id="0"></div>
<div data-map_id="0"></div>
<div data-map_id="2"></div>
<div data-map_id="2"></div>
```

I could get an array as follows.

```
map_id_array=["0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "2", "2"];
```

But I want to get an array as follows from this array or from HTML directly.

```
map_id_array=["0", "1", "2"];
```

How to do this in pure JavaScript?

Comment: Please the existed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates) how to filter duplicates with pure Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

While parsing you can make use of Sets in javascript. It will ensure values are entered only once

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set